# How to make NSDateFormatter display locale-specific date?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I am using NSDateFormatter to set my date in my iPhone app, and dates are showing up properly.  However, I am finding all the locales (my app supports up to 12 different languages) are sticking to the date format I specify via setDateFormat.  Ideally, I want the date format to appear in a form natural to the region setting for the user, instead of following my format (which works well for English but may not be natural for other locales).

Following is my code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss"];

    self.creationDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:creationTimeStamp];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution.  The key is to not call `setDateFormat` at all, and the API in iPhone would automatically pick the appropriate thing to display based on what is specified in `setDateStyle` and `setTimeStyle`.

Comment: This solution is better than using -localizedStringFromDate API because the string returned by -localizedStringFromDate will counter the timezone factor and sometimes for some regions the date / time will be irrelevant. To remove the timezone component, we need to do this additionally:     [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

Answer (score 32):

I would try the following `NSDateFormatter` API instead:

```
+ (NSString *)localizedStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date
              dateStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)dateStyle
              timeStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)timeStyle;
```

Like so:

```
self.creationDate.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:creationTimeStamp
                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

That should give you the output you're looking for, tidy up the code a little, and keep you from having to manage some spurious memory.

Comment: But what if I don't want to style it with the given styles. Instead, I want to show date like: MMM YYYY in arabic and english. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Self-contained solution with @fbrereto's design:

```
static NSString *FormatDate(NSDate *date)
{
  return [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date
                                        dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
                                        timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
}
```

Now you can simply run:

```
NSString *formattedDate = FormatDate([NSDate new]);
```

Comment: NSDateFormatter is quite expensive to create (see Bekkis post: http://www.tinymission.com/post/nsdateformatter_is_expensive).
So you should use this self contained solution only when it is called just for a very few times.
Maybe the used NSDateFormatter should be lazily allocated in a static variable.

Comment: Good point, you could also pass in _dateFormatter to the static-c function from above, and keep a reference to it from the consumer.