# IOS: date format by device language

Tags: ios, xcode, date, label

In my app I should set a label with a date (today), but the problem is that format date change in some countries; then I want to know waht's the way to obtain information about device language or other information that say me that device is used in usa or france or italy or exc...
can you help me?

Comment: Did you even do a search before posting your question?  [Here is a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348590/how-to-make-nsdateformatter-display-locale-specific-date) (and I'm voting to close yours).

Comment: but your link don't solve my doubt, I know datafromatter, I want to detect the language of device or its country usage. why did you vite to close my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale: in NSDateFormatter

> Returns a localized date format string representing the given date
>   format components arranged appropriately for the specified locale.

For example, you can specify a template like "MMMM D, YYYY" and it will change the order of the terms for the locale that you specify.

UPDATE

If you want to know the language and the region, then you should try using this:

```
[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]
```

for the current language. (Languages are coded and in the order of most recently used first.)

```
[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]
```

for the region. Locale identifiers are coded (like it_IT for Italy). For a complete list of coded locales, use `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`

See the documentation for NSLocale to find out more about language and location.

Comment: Allora a quanto pare, la vostra domanda non è sulla formattazione della data, di per sé. Volete sapere la lingua e la regione? Allora dovreste provare a utilizzare questo: `[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` per la lingua corrente. [NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] per la regione. See my updated answer.